# While loop + switch

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, switch-statement

I can't figure this out I keep getting stuck in a loop. I don't know if I have my calculation or if statements in the right areas, please I could use some help. My output is like a end of day report. I could really use the help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
// assignments
var cost, nachosCounter, moneyCollected, nachosRate, corndogRate, hotdogRate;
var hamAccum, hotdogAccum, corndogAccum, nachosAccum, hamburgerRate;
var beginDay, orderType, hamCounter, hotdogCounter, corndogCounter;
var totalHotdog, totalNachos, totalCorndog, totalHamburger, moneyCollected;    
var hamburgerRate = 4;
var hotDogRate = 2;
var cornDogRate = 3;
var nachosRate = 5;
var hamCounter = 0;
var hotdogCounter = 0;
var corndogCounter = 0;
var nachosCounter = 0;
var beginDay = "yes"
//initalizing loop
beginDay = "yes"
//start loop
while (beginDay == "yes")
{
    orderType = prompt("hamburger, hotdog, corndog, nachos", "");
    if (orderType == "hamburger")
    {
        hamCounter = hamCounter + 1;
        if (hamCounter == 1) 
        {
            hamAccum = "<br>The total number of hamburgers purchased: " + hamCounter;
        }
        else
        {
            hamAccum = hamAccum + "<br>" + hamCounter;
        }
    }
    else if (orderType == "hotdog")
    {
        hotdogCounter = hotdogCounter + 1;
        if (hotdogCounter == 1) 
        {
            hotdogAccum = "The total number of hotdog purchased:<br>" + hotdogCounter;
        }
        else
        {
            hotdogAccum = hotdogAccum + "<br>" + hotdogCounter;
        }
    }
    if (orderType == "corndog")
    {
        corndogCounter = corndogCounter + 1;
        if (corndogCounter == 1) 
        {
            corndogAccum = "<br>The total number of corndogs purchased: <br>" + corndogCounter;
        }
        else
        {
            corndogAccum = corndogAccum + "<br>" + corndogCounter;
        }
    }
    if (orderType == "nachos")
    {
        nachosCounter = nachosCounter + 1;
        if (nachosCounter == 1) 
        {
            nachosAccum = "<br>The total number of nachos purchased: <br>" + nachosCounter;
        }
        else
        {
            nachosAccum = nachosAccum + "<br>" + nachosCounter;
        }
    }
totalHotdog = hotdogCounter*hotDogRate;
totalHamburger = hamCounter*hamburgerRate;
totalCorndog = corndogCounter*cornDogRate;
totalNachos = nachosCounter*nachosRate;
moneyCollected = totalNachos+totalCorndog+totalHamburger+totalHotdog;
    beginDay = prompt("More to add?", "yes");
} 
//output
document.write(hotdogAccum);
document.write(hamAccum);
document.write(corndogAccum);
document.write(nachosAccum);
document.write("<br>The total dollar amount for hotdog: $ " + totalHotdog);
document.write("<br>The total dollar amount for hamburger: $ " + totalHamburger);
document.write("<br>The total dollar amount for corndogs:  $" + totalCorndog);
document.write("<br>The total dollar amount for nachos:  $" + totalNachos);
document.write("The total amount of money collected:  $" + moneyCollected);

// -->
</script>
```

Comment: Use tab button, Luke.

Comment: while editing your original code, i found that switch was outside the while loop. But this code (edited by Jonatahan) doesn't have that problem anymore. You can try the edited code.

Comment: yes I found that too `if(orderType == "nachos") {`. Then I can't see any reason that this code should stuck in the while loop. I tried it in console (chrome) and it worked fine.

Comment: @vdua yeah I just fixed that == nachos. and some other typing to fast errors. Thanks

Comment: how do I get my switch statement to run in the loop?

Comment: may I know why there is both `if else` and `switch` there?

Comment: I need to add the total of order types for eaches and then have those order types get my calculations for end of day $money made.

Comment: I think you could just increment `total<XYZ>` in the `if` and saves the `switch`, or calculate `total<XYZ>` out of the `while` loop as they only depends on `<XYZ>Accum`.

Comment: Ok I just redid the code and took out the switch not say if I don't order a hotdog at all I get an undefined. Is there a way to say if (no hotdog is ordered) it will write 0???

Comment: ok along with the undefined issue I need my counter not to 1,2,3,4,5 but only say the last digit counted for the output. does that make sense??please help

Comment: if (ordertype == hotdog ) { total = something } else if (ordertype == corndog) { total = something } so on and so forth - and a default else at the end set total to 0. Since you don't have else if - if you don't order hotdog total is undefined.